# Laravel 5.2 Session is not working

Tags: laravel, session

Hello I am working with the development version of Laravel 5.2 and I have a problem.

If I try this:

```
Session::set('hi', 'hello') dd(Session::get('hi'))
```

It prints "hello" but if I remove the set line and refresh the page it prints **null**

Also with the `CSRF token` it regenerates a different token every time I refresh the browser.

Native sessions **($_SESSION)** do work so it is not a browser problem.

I am using file driver but I tried cookie driver and even "native" driver and it does not work.

Do you have any idea of what could be going on here?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in laravel 5.2 you need to use "web" middleware for your problem,like that

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['web']], function () {
   // here you should put your routes
 });
```

Answer (score 2):

@paranoid is right, you should use it like this.

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

Route::group(['middleware' => ['web']], function () {
    Route::get('/', function () {
        return view('welcome');
    });
    Route::get('/setSession', function (Request $request) {
        return $request->session()->put('key', 'value');
    });
    Route::get('/getSession', function (Request $request) {
        return $request->session()->get('key', 'value');
    });
});
```